# In-page Navigation with DD4T

Tags: dd4t, componentpresentation, navigation

I'd like to suggest to my technical team (DD4T Java) a DD4T version of [In-page Component Presentation-based Navigation](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/12/yet-another-sdl-tridion-navigational.html). In other words, we want to create something like the following.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#CP1"></li>
  ...
  <li><a href="#CPN"></li>
</ul>
```

On the same page we have the Component Presentations (CPs):

```
<div id="CP1">...</div>
...
<div id="CPN">...</div>
```

*Bookmark link and matching ID might be based on order, title, or "heading" fields. This is not [Structure-Group based Navigation as mentioned in Robert's question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/642/46).*

This seems equivalent to one of [Harold's answers](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/5642/46), that includes:

- "**Widget**" -- New Component Template (and maybe dummy Component) to output the details
- Matching DD4T ComponentPresentationRenderer calls the action to output navigation

**At a high-level, what should my developer work on to get the Component titles (or select fields) from the CPs on a given page?**

- Would a view for each link make sense?
- Should the bookmark link markup go in the page view?

Assumptions:

- The navigational links are not on every page. They would be added to a page via Page metadata (`include bookmark nav` option or with a "Widget" CP that editors place on the page)
- The markup would ideally be the same, but may differ by pages (abstracting the links would be a good idea)
- Pages embed CPs dynamically (on the page, but with dynamic Component Templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would go for a custom page template;

In here you create for the location of the navigation

```
<c:forEach var="componentPresentation" items="${pageModel.componentPresentations}">
<li><a href="#${componentPresentation.component.title}>${componentPresentation.component.title}</a></li>
</c:forEach>
```

*(for the spaces you can create a custom function)*

And on the content location where the components come you keep the normal repeat of component presentations;

```
<dd4t:componentpresentations />
```

Make sure the componentPresentations have some kind of identifier that matches the ankers in the top navigation.

Hope this answers you question or a direction;

Comment: A Page Template works. For identifiers, we could use something from the Component and Template and maybe the position just in case of duplicates.